# Hibernate 6 Error: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityKey.getIdentifier()" because "this.entityKey" is null

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

We are migrating a legacy application from Spring Boot 2.7 -> 3.0.2, with the associated change to Hibernate 6.

We are getting the following error on running the application:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityKey.getIdentifier()" because "this.entityKey" is null
```

Our *persistence.xml* provider is

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

There is a Hibernate ticket that was apparently entered recently for this error:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16075?filter=-4

According to this ticket, this bug is fixed in Hibernate **6.1.7**. We added the following extra Hibernate Core dependency to our POM and rebuilt, but **the error is still occurring**.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Any other possible solutions?

**UPDATE** We noticed this happens on a Composite Key. Our initiation suspicion was that some Composite Key parts were NULL, which may have been allowed before, but then it turned out all the parts were non-NULL. Something about the Composite Key, however, caused this error.

Answer (score 1):

It was never ok to have nullable parts in a composite primary key. If that worked before, it was by mistake. The very definition of a primary key is that all columns must be not null and unique.

Answer (score 0):

Something about a **Composite Primary Key** caused this error in Hibernate 6. We verified that if we replace the Composite Key with a simple 1-column PK, the error goes away. It looks like it's a good idea to replace Composite Keys with real single ID columns to fix this issue in this release of Hibernate.